# Problema con validaciones a input datetime-local con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Resulta que tengo 2 input del tipo **`datetime-local`** en un formulario sobre reservas de cabañas, y  quisiera saber si es posible establecer unas validaciones que impida al usuario interactuar libremente con los controles.

Como 1era validación, intento lograr que en uno al ingresar una fecha el otro no permita el ingreso de una fecha menor a la ya seleccionada.

Es decir, por ejemplo:

Estos son los input:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="fecha1" name="datetime_1" required="required"/>
<br>
<input type="datetime-local" id="fecha2" name="datetime_2" required="required"/>
```

Si en el primero se seleccionó la siguiente fecha: `05-12-2018 08:00:00.` El segundo **no debería permitir** la ***selección*** de una fecha menor a esa. Tampoco debería permitir ***escribir*** una fecha manualmente que sea menor a la escogida, y por último no debería permitir ***aumentarla*** con los selectores del control **( ↕ ).** ¿Se puede lograr?

De momento como **idea** tengo lo siguiente:

```
$('#input_datetime-local').change(function(e){

    if ($('#input_datetime-local2').val() < $('#input_datetime-local').val()) {

        $.alert({
            title: '<i class="fa fa-danger"></i>ERROR',
            content: '<p>FECHA INTRODUCIDA INVALIDA</p>',
        });
        e.preventDefault();

        /*DESDE AQUI YA NO SE MUY BIEN COMO VALIDAR LO SIGUIENTE QUE 
          EXPLIQUE ANTERIORMENTE*/
    }
}
```

Pero no funciona.

Además como 2da validación, me gustaría establecer que la hora que se pueda seleccionar y escribir no sea una hora menor a 08:00 ni mayor a 23:00.

Para esta 2da validación tengo como **idea** lo siguiente, pero no sé muy bien cómo añadir a esta validación que impida escribir y seleccionar una hora menor a 08:00 y mayor a 23:00:

```
$('#input_datetime-local').change(function(e){

    var today = new Date();

    $('#new_date_fin').val(today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2)+'T'+'08'+':'+'00');
}
```

Y como 3era y última validación me gustaría establecer el incremento de solo la hora que aumente de 1 en 1, y que los minutos queden *'deshabilitados'.*

Y para esta ultima opcion tengo lo siguiente como **idea**, aunque funciona con un botón. Cuando mi idea es que sea utilizando los controles **( ↕ )** del `datetime-local:`

```
<label>Date:</label>&nbsp;<input type="datetime-local" id="new_date">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Inténtalo</button>


<script type="text-javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      var today = new Date();
      $('#new_date').val(today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2)+'T'+today.getHours()+':'+today.getMinutes());
      document.getElementById("new_date").stepUp(60);
    }
</script>
```

¿Es posible todo aquello?

Como dato extra añado que al momento de que el sitio se carga siempre, el 1er input viene con un valor asignado por default, el cual es la fecha actual del sistema con una hora inicial de 08:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, decirte que existen librerías de Javascript muy intuitivas y que te facilitarían mucho las cosas a la hora de hacer lo que quieres. **Datepicker** de **Jquery UI** es la que yo suelo usar y me da muy buenos resultados y se encuentra ampliamente soportada por los navegadores. Si aun así quieres seguir haciéndote daño al tratar de usar este tipo de input, he estado trasteando con él (nunca había trabajado con este tipo de input) y te pongo las soluciones que he encontrado.

Mediante el manejo de los atributos **HTML** que este tipo de inputs pone a nuestra disposición, sumado al manejo de algún que otro evento de Javascript puedes solucionar la mayoría de las cosas que expones.

**Cuestión 1**

> Si en el primero se seleccionó la siguiente fecha: 05-12-2018
>   08:00:00. El segundo no debería permitir la selección de una fecha
>   menor a esa.

Esto podrías solucionarlo con el uso del atributo `min`, modificando el `min` a **fecha2** para que tenga como valor mínimo el seleccionado en **fecha1**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#fecha1').change(function() {
      var fecha1 = $(this).val();
      var fecha1_objeto = new Date(fecha1);
      
      if (devuelve_horas(fecha1_objeto) < 8) {
        fecha1_objeto.setHours(9);
        fecha1_objeto.setMinutes(0);
        alert(fecha1_objeto.toISOString().substring(0, 16));
        $(this).val(fecha1_objeto.toISOString().substring(0, 16));
      }
      
      if (devuelve_horas(fecha1_objeto) == 23 && devuelve_minutos(fecha1_objeto) > 0) {
        fecha1_objeto.setHours(24);
        fecha1_objeto.setMinutes(0);
        alert(fecha1_objeto.toISOString().substring(0, 16));
        $(this).val(fecha1_objeto.toISOString().substring(0, 16));
      }

      $('#fecha2').attr('min', fecha1);
    });
    
    $('#fecha2').change(function() {
      var fecha1 = $('#fecha1').val();
      var fecha2 = $(this).val();
      var fecha1_objeto = new Date(fecha1);
      var fecha2_objeto = new Date(fecha2);
      
      if (devuelve_horas(fecha2_objeto) < 8) {
        fecha2_objeto.setHours(9);
        fecha2_objeto.setMinutes(0);
        $(this).val(fecha2_objeto.toISOString().substring(0, 16));
      }
      
      if (devuelve_horas(fecha2_objeto) == 23 && devuelve_minutos(fecha2_objeto) > 0) {
        fecha2_objeto.setHours(24);
        fecha2_objeto.setMinutes(0);
        $(this).val(fecha2_objeto.toISOString().substring(0, 16));
      }
      
      if (fecha2_objeto > fecha1_objeto) {
       $('#fecha2').val(fecha1);
      }
      
    });
    
 
});

function devuelve_horas (fecha) {
  var horas = fecha.getHours();
  return horas;
}

function devuelve_minutos (fecha) {
  var minutos = fecha.getMinutes();
  return minutos;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local" id="fecha1"/>
<br>
<input type="datetime-local" id="fecha2" name="datetime_2" min="" required="required"/>
```

**Cuestión 2**

> Tampoco debería permitir escribir una fecha manualmente que sea menor
>   a la escogida.

Resolviendo el problema que tenía a la hora de no poder restringir el que la hora de **fecha2** fuese mayor que la de **fecha1** estando ambas en el mismo día, solucioné también el problema de tu segunda pregunta. Tras transformar el `string` que te devuelve el `val()` del `input` a un objeto `date` pude compararlos entre ellos para saber cual era mayor y en el caso de que **fecha2** lo fuese, darle como valor el que **fecha1** puso de tope.

El código que resuelve esta segunda cuestión se encuentra integrado en el que puse en la primera cuestión.

**Cuestión 3**

> Por último no debería permitir aumentarla con los selectores del control ( ↕ ).

Esta cuestión se resolvió de igual manera que la segunda. Al comparar ambos objetos fecha mediante el evento **change**, cuando se tratara de incrementar el valor del `input` por encima de permitido, al perder el foco, el elemento retornaría de nuevo al valor tope.

**Cuestión 4**

> Me gustaría establecer que la hora que se pueda seleccionar y escribir no sea > una hora menor a 08:00 ni mayor a 23:00.

He añadido al código esta nueva funcionalidad. Mediante los `seters` y `geters` que tienen los objetos Date(), compruebo si la hora es menor a las 8:00 o superior a las 23:00 y en caso afirmativo la modifico para que esté dentro del rango.

Como el `datetime-local` es muy rígido con el `string` que tiene que recibir como `val()` opté por usar un **substring** para quitarme lo que me sobraba de la cadena que te devuelve la función `toISOString()` de los objetos `Date()`.

**Cuestión 5**

> Establecer el incremento de solo la hora que aumente de 1 en 1, y que
>   los minutos queden 'deshabilitados'.

Esto ya tiene más difícil solución. Pienso que los tiros pueden andar por el atributo `step` de los `datetime-local`, pero no he dado de momento con ello. No obstante seguiré investigando en otro momento y si diese con ello lo publico por aquí ^^

**Conclusiones**

- El `input` me ha parecido bastante engorroso de usar. Tardé unos cuantos minutos en entender el por qué no se me ejecutaba el evento `change` asociado a ambos `input` (hasta que no rellenas también los campos de **horas** y **minutos** no considera que el `input` ha cambiado).
- El que cada navegador pueda mostrarlo de diferentes maneras (al igual que ocurre con otros `input` de **HTML**, no termina de convencerme. Por lo que esta sería una razón de peso para decantarme por una librería.
- Dar estilos a este tipo de elementos que se muestran de maneras diferentes dependiendo del navegador es un verdadero quebradero de cabeza.
- El que no esté soportado por los navegadores **Firefox** y **Safari** en sus versiones de escritorio quizás sea la mayor pega que le veo.

[Referencia usada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

Comment: Editada la respuesta para completarla del todo. (me había quedado a medias por motivos de tiempo)

Comment: Gracias amigo lo voy a probar y adaptar a mi codigo, y te comento ^-^